# zk session serialization and Shiro/EhCache

Tags: java, session, ehcache, zk, shiro

I have Shiro managing security, and AspectJ handling authentication checks and login page redirects for all zk viewmodel classes. I have EhCache handling session persistence.

How the main issue here is that `org.zkoss.bind.AnnotateBinder` has a non-transient, non-serializable member (`org.zkoss.util.logging.Log`) resulting in Shiro throwing a `java.io.NotSerializableException` which Jetty 8 swallows but totally stops Tomcat 7 dead in its tracks.

I have setup ZK using the org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.SerializableUiFactory, which should create `Serializable` sessions (although this claim is patently false).

Now I've tried several things, short of modifying the ZK sourcecode. But before I do this, I'd like to know if anyone has any ideas for different stop-gap solutions. (Like a setting in Shiro and/or EhCache, that lets it just ignore non-serializable fields silently, without throwing an exception? Or perhaps some setting in Tomcat 7 that I'm missing which makes it swallow or ignore exceptions like Jetty does?

Comment: can you add a catch expression to your handling for starts?

Comment: Not really. All of this is being done in (I suspect) the ShiroFilter, safely out of the reach of meddlesome developers. :)